# How to serialize Wi-Fi config object to wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: c#, serialization, wpa

there

Here is an example of wpa_supplicant.conf

```
# allow frontend (e.g., wpa_cli) to be used by all users in 'wheel' group
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=wheel
#
# home network; allow all valid ciphers
network={
    ssid="home"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="very secret passphrase"
}
#
# work network; use EAP-TLS with WPA; allow only CCMP and TKIP ciphers
network={
    ssid="work"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP TKIP
    group=CCMP TKIP
    eap=TLS
    identity="user@example.com"
    ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
    client_cert="/etc/cert/user.pem"
    private_key="/etc/cert/user.prv"
    private_key_passwd="password"
}
```

I have an object in C# code named Wificonfig, which is used to save ssid, key_mgmt, psk and etc., I want to use C# code to create the file if does not exist, how to serialize the object and create the file, is there anyone could provide some sample code for that?
I'm not sure if C# serialize tech. is the suitable method, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try "[Daabli](http://daabli.codeplex.com/)". This is a (de)serializer that serializes to a plain-text, C style format. It also allows you fine control over serialization of specific fields.